# How to send array of data through soap request in ios?

Tags: ios, soap

I am facing problem while sending array of data in soap request.

Using following code, I am able to get below response.

SOAP message requets:

```
 NSString *soapMessage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                           "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns=\"http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/services/TEST_SRVC\">\n"
                           "<soap:Body>\n"
                           "<TEST_SRVC_OP/>\n"
                           "<OPRID>%@</OPRID>\n"
                           "<PWD>%@</PWD>\n"
                           "<REQUEST_ID>%@</REQUEST_ID>\n"
                           "<PORT_CD>%@</PORT_CD>\n"
                           "<SIZE_CD>%@</SIZE_CD>\n"
                           "</soap:Body>\n"
                           "</soap:Envelope>\n",strUserName,strPassword,strRequestID,strSize] ;
```

Generated soap message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/services/TEST_SRVC">
<soap:Body>
<TEST_SRVC_OP/>
<OPRID> username </OPRID>
<PWD> passowrd </PWD>
<REQUEST_ID> R123 </REQUEST_ID>
<PORT_CD> TEST1 </PORT_CD>
   <SIZE_CD>40</SIZE_CD>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But, I need to generate soap message like this.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/services/TEST_SRVC" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <TEST_SRVC_OP />
      <OPRID>username</OPRID>
      <PWD>passowrd</PWD>
      <REQUEST_ID>R123</REQUEST_ID>
      <Detailrow>
         <PORT_CD>TEST1</PORT_CD>
         <SIZE_CD>40</SIZE_CD>
      </Detailrow>
      <Detailrow>
         <PORT_CD>TEST2</PORT_CD>
         <SIZE_CD>60</SIZE_CD>
      </Detailrow>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strSoapMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                  @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                  "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">"
                  "<soap12:Body>"
                  "<GetPortfolioList xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                  "<EmailID>%@</EmailID>"
                  "<Password>%@</Password>"
                  "<TradingGameID>%d</TradingGameID>"
                  "</GetPortfolioList>"
                  "</soap12:Body>"
                  "</soap12:Envelope>",gameUserName,gamePassword,gameid];


    //---print it to the Debugger Console for verification---
    NSLog(@"soapMsg..........%@",strSoapMsg);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.sirus/Process/process.asmx"];
    req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //---set the headers---

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[strSoapMsg length]];
    [req addValue:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetPortfolioList"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    //---set the HTTP method and body---

    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody: [strSoapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if (conn)
    {
        webPortFolio = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `data` for `PORT_CD` and `SIZE_CD` or don't then `create` like given below example:

```
NSString *strUserName =@"username";
NSString *strPassword =@"password";
NSString *strRequestID =@"R123";

//Here all port_cd with size_cd here
NSArray *arrData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"TEST1",@"portcd",@"50",@"sizecd",nil],[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"TEST2",@"portcd",@"60",@"sizecd",nil],[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"TEST3",@"portcd",@"70",@"sizecd",nil],nil];

//create soap message
NSString *soapMessage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                       "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns=\"http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/services/TEST_SRVC\">\n"
                       "<soap:Body>\n"
                       "<TEST_SRVC_OP/>\n"
                       "<OPRID>%@</OPRID>\n"
                       "<PWD>%@</PWD>\n"
                       "<REQUEST_ID>%@</REQUEST_ID>\n",strUserName,strPassword,strRequestID];

//Append port_cd and size_cd here to soap message
for (NSDictionary *dictData in arrData)
{
    NSString *strPortCD = [dictData objectForKey:@"portcd"];
    NSString *strSizeCD = [dictData objectForKey:@"sizecd"];
    soapMessage = [soapMessage stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Detailrow>\n<PORT_CD>%@</PORT_CD>\n<SIZE_CD>%@</SIZE_CD>\n</Detailrow>\n",strPortCD,strSizeCD]];
}

soapMessage = [soapMessage stringByAppendingString:@"</soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>"];

NSLog(@"soapMessage : %@",soapMessage);
```